# Cleaning DataFrame column that has websites URL in python by iterating over row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have DataFrame such as below. I want to iterate over a row of data and when it is `https://www.ecodibergamo.it/`, write website and otherwise get two segment(word) after the website. the out put I want, is like below,
I wrote a code to get two word after, but I don't know how to expand it to my data frame.

```
my_string="https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/Cronaca/"
print(my_string.split("https://www.ecodibergamo.it/",1)[1] )
```

```
        Referer
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/bergamo-citta/bergamo-nellolimpo-della-guida-rossada-vittorio-al-top-new-entry-impronte_1327138_11/',
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/bassa-bergamasca/treviglio-chiedono-reddito-di-cittadinanzama-nei-nostri-registri-risultano-def_1327223_11/',
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/bergamo-citta/il-natale-a-bergamo-dal-24-novembreal-via-la-ruota-panoramica-in-centro_1327082_11/',
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',
```

```
        Referer.                                      text_clean 
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',                      website
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',                      website
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/bergamo-citta/
bergamo-nellolimpo-della-guida-rossada-vittorio-al-
top-new-entry-impronte_1327138_11/',                 stories/bergamo-citta
 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/.              stories/bassa-bergamasca                              
bassa-bergamasca/treviglio-chiedono-
reddito-di-cittadinanzama-nei-nostri-
registri-risultano-def_1327223_11/',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to replace the URL and using `split()` and `join()` get the first two after the website link

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',
                           'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',
                           'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/bergamo-citta/bergamo-nellolimpo-della-guida-rossada-vittorio-al-top-new-entry-impronte_1327138_11/',
                           'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/bassa-bergamasca/treviglio-chiedono-reddito-di-cittadinanzama-nei-nostri-registri-risultano-def_1327223_11/',
                           'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/stories/bergamo-citta/il-natale-a-bergamo-dal-24-novembreal-via-la-ruota-panoramica-in-centro_1327082_11/',
                           'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/',
                           'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/']})
```

Then write a replace function like this:

```
def replace_urls(url):
    if url == 'https://www.ecodibergamo.it/':
        url = 'website'
    else:
        url = '/'.join(re.sub('https://www.ecodibergamo.it/', '', url).split('/')[:2])
    return url
```

Next, apply the `replace_url` to all rows of the column:

```
df['URL'] = [replace_urls(i) for i in df['URL']]
```

The output will be:

```
      URL
0   website
1   website
2   stories/bergamo-citta
3   stories/bassa-bergamasca
4   stories/bergamo-citta
5   website
6   website
```